# Cox regression problem with time varying covariates

Tags: sas, cox-model

I was working on a cox regression problem and was refering to this link:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect050.htm

I have few questions regarding to this:

As in the example mentioned, can we feed missing values to model?
Also how do we handle multicollinearity in such a data setup.

Comment: If you don't get good answers here, you may find them in [Paul Allison's book on survival analysis with SAS](http://www.amazon.com/Survival-Analysis-Using-SAS-Practical/dp/1599946408)